# POODLE Ciphers !SSLv3 = Protocol or cipher suite mismatch

Tags: openssl, pound, poodle

According to: [ANNOUNCE: Pound - reverse proxy and load balancer - v2.7d / Robert Segall](http://www.apsis.ch/pound/pound_list/archive/2014/2014-10/1413628998000) , following enhancement was added:

```
- added "Disable PROTO" directives (fix for Poodle vulnerability)
```

My system:

```
[root@6svprx01 ~]# uname -a
Linux 6svprx01.XXX.org 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 16 01:56:35 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@6svprx01 ~]# rpm -q Pound
Pound-2.6-2.el6.x86_64
[root@6svprx01 ~]# grep Ciphers /etc/pound.cfg
    Ciphers    "ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM"
[root@6svprx01 ~]#
```

... to address POODLE SSLv3, I added `!SSLv3` into `Ciphers`.

Yet while using `Qualys SSL Labs - Projects / SSL Server Test` to test, I get `Protocol or cipher suite mismatch` in `Handshake Simulation`.

Is there a way to address this *WITHOUT* upgrading to Pound v2.7d (beta) and then using new directives?

Comment: Which one gave you a "Protocol or cipher suite mismatch"?

Comment: @MichaelHampton list is quite large, so I paste it here: http://pastebin.com/X9v3H3GZ

Comment: That's most of them... You need [a new list of ciphers](http://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/).

Comment: Still looking for a solution to this myself. I'd add a bounty if I had enough ServerFault rep :-(

Comment: @anschauung I posted solution for you (and others) in answer section)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one can use [goochjj/pound at pcidss/v2.6](https://github.com/goochjj/pound/tree/pcidss/v2.6) branch, which is Pound 2.6, plus cipher and protocol patches necessary (initially) to pass PCI compliance, and as part of that is the directive to disable SSL3.

```
# grep DisableSSL /etc/pound.cfg
    DisableSSLv3
    DisableSSLv2
#
```

*** UPDATE ***

`DisableSSLv3` appears to be `unknown directive` using non-patched `Version 2.6`, use `-SSLv3:-SSLv2` inside of `Ciphers`.

Comment: Perfect -- many thanks! Adding a few additional notes in a separate response, in case others come across them as well.

Answer (score 1):

@alexus's answer above worked perfectly for me. Adding some additional notes here in case others come across this page as I did. There doesn't seem to be a lot of good guidance out there for this specific combination of problems.

1) The reason for the original problem is that the non-patched version of Pound disables all SSLv3 ciphers when one adds `!SSLv3` to `Ciphers`. TLS mostly depends on the same ciphers, and won't work well without them.

2) Older versions of GCC will give an error when you try to run `./configure` on the patched version in @alexus's link, since it doesn't recognize the `-Wno-unused-result` flag. I removed that manually and everything seems to run fine after.

3) The `DisableSSLv3` directive goes inside the `ListenHTTPs` block in `pound.cfg` (next to the `Ciphers` directive)

Comment: `DisableSSLv3` appears to be `unknown directive` using non-patched `Version 2.6`; I wasn't able to use `!SSLv3` inside of `Ciphers`, yet `-SSLv3:-SSLv2` works!