# Disabling SSLv3 and SSLv2 Protocol On My Ubuntu 14.04 Server

Tags: ssl, poodle

I recently installed a SSL Certificate on my server. Then I tried out [this tool](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) to test my newly installed SSL certificate on my server and see if there is no problem.

It turned out that it has a problem with **SSL 3** protocol, saying that it is insecure because of vulnerability of from POODLE attack.

The page suggests to disable SSL 3 to mitigate it.

So I searched the Internet on how to disable *SSLv3 and SSLv2** on Apache 2.4 server.

I've found several tutorials that says... to disable **SSLv3 and SSLv2** on my Ubuntu 14.04 server with Apache 2.4, I have to edit all instances of `SSLProtocol all` on all files inside `/etc/apache2`, and change it to `SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3`.

I've already done the following, but still SSL Lab's SSL Server Test Tool reports the same issue.

Already added this to all of my vhost and all config file that has `SSLProtocol`...

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
```

### About My Server Setup

On my server, I've setup **Pound Proxy** with **Varnish Cache**.

I did this because Varnish is not able to do it's thing using HTTPS, and so I setup **Pound** and use Varnish as it's backend.

The setup is working fine, Varnish is caching on HTTPS.

My SSL certificate was installed properly, I have confirmed that using online tools from Digicert and SSL Labs.

SSL Pem files used with **Pound** contains info extracted from `.key`, `.crt` and `CA.pem`.

### My Server Details

Below are some details about my server. It host a single Wordpress instance on it, it's in production.

#### Ports

- Apache - on port 8080
- Apache `ports.conf` and `sites-available/myvhost.conf` -

  ```
  <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
      Listen 9443
  ```
- Apache
- Varnish Backend - port 8080
- Varnish `.vcl` - DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80"
- Pound listens on port 443, configured using `ListenHTTPS`

The server is provisioned using **Tuxlite**, which I've downloaded from the following page:

```
https://github.com/Mins/TuxLite
```

#### LSB Release output:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

#### Apache output:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Mar 10 2015 13:05:59
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:27
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.1-dev, APR-UTIL 1.5.3
Compiled using: APR 1.5.1-dev, APR-UTIL 1.5.3
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     event
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

#### Pound output:

```
starting...
Version 2.6
  Configuration switches:
    --enable-cert1l
Exiting...
```

#### Varnish version:

```
varnishd (varnish-4.0.3 revision b8c4a34)
Copyright (c) 2006 Verdens Gang AS
Copyright (c) 2006-2014 Varnish Software AS
```

**How could I disable SSLv2 and SSLv3 Protocol on my server?**

### UPDATE

I've inserted the following entries in my `/etc/pound/pound.cfg` file:

```
ListenHTTPS
    ...
    Cert "---"
    Ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:EDH+aRSA:-RC4:EECDH+aRSA+RC4:EECDH+RC4:EDH+aRSA+RC4:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS:RC4+SHA"
    ....
```

And now I got a **C** Grade in SSL Labs.

SSL 3 Insecure Handshake Simulation Errs for **IE6 / XP**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [POODLE Ciphers !SSLv3 = Protocol or cipher suite mismatch](http://serverfault.com/questions/639242/poodle-ciphers-sslv3-protocol-or-cipher-suite-mismatch)

Comment: The problem here seems that you haven't described the linkages between Apache, Pound and Varnish. Chances are that Pound is the part that is the component that is 'terminating' the client's SSL session, and so that is where the change must be made. Pound will reverse-proxy to Varnish, which will reverse proxy to Apache. If there is SSL between Pound and Varnish, or Varnish and Apache, those are separate SSL connections and completely separate from the User to Pound connection.

Comment: Please see another question in my earlier comment, if it doesn't help, please  post full configuration of `/etc/pound.conf`. Your apache and Varnish configuration isn't relevant here as ssllabs only interacted with Pound.

Comment: @masegaloeh - I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, so my Pound config file is located at `/etc/pound/pound.cfg`. I also commented on Ahmed I.'s answer below, it was the same answer as alexus gave on his post. Putting `DisableSSLv2 and v3` in my `/etc/pound/pound.cfg` before `Cipher` directive didn't help, it throws error saying `unknown directive`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your running Pound with SSL on port 443.

To fix this issue, Have following lines in /etc/pound.cfg and restart pound and test

`DisableSSLv3 
 DisableSSLv2`

Comment: It throws unknown directive error.